# Vulkan vkCreateInstance - Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000

Tags: c, exception, graphics, vulkan

I am trying to write a basic program using Vulkan, but I keep getting a runtime error.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDC27A8DBE (vulkan-1.dll) in VulkanTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.
```

This seems to be a relatively common issue, resulting from a failure to initialize the arguments of the vkCreateInstance function. I have tried all of the solutions I found proposed to others, even initializing things I am fairly certain I don't need to, and I still haven't been able to solve the problem. The program is written in C using the MSVC compiler.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "SDL.h"
#include "vulkan\vulkan.h"
#include "System.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error");
    }
    printf("Success");

    //Initialize Vulkan
    VkInstance VulkanInstance;

    VkApplicationInfo VulkanApplicationInfo;
    VulkanApplicationInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    VulkanApplicationInfo.pNext = 0;
    VulkanApplicationInfo.pApplicationName = "VulkanTest";
    VulkanApplicationInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    VulkanApplicationInfo.pEngineName = "VulkanTest";
    VulkanApplicationInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    VulkanApplicationInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;


    VkInstanceCreateInfo VulkanCreateInfo = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    VulkanCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    VulkanCreateInfo.pNext = 0;
    VulkanCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &VulkanApplicationInfo;
    VulkanCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = 1;
    VulkanCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation";
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(0, VulkanCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount,             
    VulkanCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames);

    //Create Vulkan Instance
    if(vkCreateInstance(&VulkanCreateInfo, 0, &VulkanInstance) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Vulkan instance was not created");
    }

    //Create SDL Window
    SDL_Window* window;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("VulkanTest", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 0, 0, SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN || SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP);

    SDL_Delay(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That there is a NULL pointer. Did you forget to initialize something? Step through in a debugger to find out what that pointer is supposed to represent.

Comment: Please tag with the language you're using. Don't slap C++ on C questions.

Comment: It's a c++ library. I thought it might be relevant. And which null pointer? I believe there are several.

Comment: This is C code. Tag with the visible part of the problem. Consider: Someone watching the tag trying to answer C++ questions will be looking for C++ code.

Comment: `ppEnabledLayerNames = "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"`. How does this work? Seems like a type error. One is `char*` other is `char**`.

Comment: `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(0,VulkanCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount,            VulkanCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames);` This is should not compile either. You pass `uint32_t` but the parameter is `uint32_t*`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the call to `vkCreateInstance()` is what is crashing?  I have not tried to debug the code you have shown (that is your job), but just looking at the calls that the code is making, it should be the call to `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties()` that is crashing (if it even compiles at all!).

The 2nd parameter of `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties()` expects a `uint32_t*` pointer, but you are passing in a `uint32_t` value (`VulkanCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount`) that has been initialized to 0.  So, that would make the `pPropertyCount` parameter be a NULL pointer (if it even compiles).

You are passing `VulkanCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames` in the 3rd parameter (if that even compiles), and `ppEnabledExtensionNames` has been initialized to NULL.  Per the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties.html) for `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties()`:

> **If `pProperties` is NULL, then the number of extensions properties available is returned in `pPropertyCount`**. Otherwise, `pPropertyCount` must point to a variable set by the user to the number of elements in the `pProperties` array, and on return **the variable is overwritten** with the number of structures actually written to `pProperties`.

Since `pPropertCount` is NULL, `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties()` has nowhere to write the property count to!  That would certainly cause an Access Violation trying to write to address 0x0000000000000000.

The documentation clears states:

> `pPropertyCount` **must** be a valid pointer to a `uint32_t` value

On top of that, your call to `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties()` is just logically wrong anyway, because the 3rd parameter expects a pointer to an array of `VkExtensionProperties` structs, but `VulkanCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames` is a pointer to an array of `const char*` UTF-8 strings instead.

In other words, you should not be using `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties()` to initialize criteria for the call to `vkCreateInstance()`.  You are completely misusing `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties()`.  You probably meant to use [`SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions) instead, eg:

```cpp
uint32_t ExtensionCount = 0;
if (!SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(NULL, &ExtensionCount, NULL))
{
    ...
}

const char **ExtensionNames = (const char **) SDL_malloc(sizeof(const char *) * ExtensionCount);
if (!ExtensionNames)
{
    ...
}

if (!SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(NULL, &ExtensionCount, ExtensionNames))
{
    SDL_free(ExtensionNames);
    ...
}

VulkanCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = ExtensionCount;
VulkanCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = ExtensionNames;

if (vkCreateInstance(&VulkanCreateInfo, 0, &VulkanInstance) != VK_SUCCESS)
{
    ...
}

SDL_free(ExtensionNames);
...
```

Comment: I am using parts of that tutorial, but SDL2 rather than GLFW. As it turns out, SDL2 provides a similar function for getting extensions. I will see about using that.